# EF Core's 'HasDefaultValueSql' cannot set current datetime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a model for a `UserProfile` which contains a field for when the user is created. I would like EF Core to automatically set the value of this field to the current datetime, whenever a new row is added to the database. To achieve this, I have made the following model:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    public UserProfile(string username, string email)
    {
        Username = username ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(username));
        Email = email;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; init; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string Username { get; init; }
    public string Email { get; private set; } = "";
    public DateTime Created { get; init; }
}
```

In the `DbContext` I have overridden the `OnModelCreating()` method and specified that the field `UserProfile.Created` should by default be set to the SQL value `GETDATE()` (I have also tried with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`).

```
public class UserProfileContext : DbContext
{
    public UserProfileContext(DbContextOptions<UserProfileContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>().ToTable("Account");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>()
            .Property(u => u.Created)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("GETDATE()");     
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

But when I create a new user and request it back, I just get the following response:

```
[
  {
    "id": "3a33c8ad-7581-4adc-8c91-a65d40ec008e",
    "username": "string",
    "email": "string",
    "created": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
  }
]
```

I cannot look directly in the database, since I'm using [EF Core InMemory](https://entityframeworkcore.com/providers-inmemory). What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you feel difference `HasDefaultValueSql` - SQL and InMemory? Only real database parses SQL and `GETDATE()` is T-SQL function.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I haven't had the chance to try it on a SQL Database yet, as I haven't set one up. I assumed that InMemory provided the same functionality (or at least the most common things), but that assumption might be wrong?

Comment: Actually no. It is just wraps collections of objects and ignores everything SQL related. `EF.Functions` especially. InMemory provider is just for simple testing. Refer to original [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

Comment: This seems perfectly reasonable as long as you assume the server has a broken clock that's stuck at `default(DateTime)`... it also highlights an issue: using a default constraint on the SQL side to fill this value means the server sets the time, rather than the client. This makes some sense for internal values that record when a row was created, but for business values that hold semantic meaning having the client explicitly set the value is more useful. (Even if you have a DB default for a fallback.)

Comment: As it turns out it was a case of missing support in EF Core InMemory. I tried settings up a local sql db and it works in that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Inmemory is not a relational  provider